# Redmine API giving Subject cannot be blank

Tags: redmine-api

I am trying to use curl to create a issue in Redmine 4.0.3-stable

I at first was trying to put the project id in the json but got more errors.

I tried setting the privileges on the role the user with the API key
XXXXXX below to everything (needed that for this role anyway) but
still got the same results, this user (myself) can create issues in
the web interface and via email just fine.

```
curl -k -H "application/xml" \
    -H "X-Redmine-Api-Key: XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX" \
    -X POST  \
    https://redmine-2.mdtsoft.com:9292/projects/incoming/issues.json \
    -d ' { "issue": { "Subject": "Example", } } '
```

I expect that the system will create a new issue in the incoming project

I get:

```
{"errors":["Subject cannot be blank"]}
```

Comment: Did you ever figure this issue out?

Answer (score 0):

Redmine REST API is case sensitive. Change "Subject" to "subject".

Source: https://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/Rest_Issues#Creating-an-issue